# Is there a method to change URL using namespaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to change the URL name.

This is my routes.rb:

```
namespace :user_management do
  resources :user do
    collection do
      get 'main'
    end
  end
end

match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

Rake routes:

```
                              Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
                                root GET      /                                        user_management/login#login
user_main_user_management_user_index GET      /user_management/user/main(.:format)     user_management/user#main
          user_management_user_index GET      /user_management/user(.:format)          user_management/user#index
                                     POST     /user_management/user(.:format)          user_management/user#create
            new_user_management_user GET      /user_management/user/new(.:format)      user_management/user#new
           edit_user_management_user GET      /user_management/user/:id/edit(.:format) user_management/user#edit
                user_management_user GET      /user_management/user/:id(.:format)      user_management/user#show
                                     PATCH    /user_management/user/:id(.:format)      user_management/user#update
                                     PUT      /user_management/user/:id(.:format)      user_management/user#update
                                     DELETE   /user_management/user/:id(.:format)      user_management/user#destroy
                                     GET|POST /:controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))   :controller#:action
```

My URL is:

```
localhost/user_management/user/main
```

And I want:

```
localhost/user_main
```

I tried this but it is not working:

```
namespace :user_management do
  resources :user do
    collection do
      get 'main', as: :user_main
    end
  end
end
```

I tried this but is not working either:

```
namespace :user_management do
  resources :user do
    collection do
      get '/user_main', as: "user_management/user#main
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your last code is syntactically invalid.

Comment: Yes i know i don't know what to try.

Comment: First you figure out why it's not syntactically correct. I'd suggest looking at what IRB shows as its line marker as it interprets it. `3"` is significant and reading the IRB documentation will explain what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
match "user_admin", :to => "user_management/user#main"
```

Comment: I got Couldn't find User with 'id'=main

Comment: what id are you talking about, thats not a css

Answer (score 0):

you can do like in example:

```
get 'exit', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: :logout # url => /logout
```

[FROM RAILS ROUTING](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes)

Comment: I tried get 'main', to: 'user_management/user#main', as: :main and i'm getting the url http://localhost:3000/user_management/user/main